# Dealing with Conditionals in Stash

Tags: stash, parse-order, parse

So I have the following code snippet which is working fine:

```
{exp:stash:set name="market_ids" parse_tags="yes"}
{exp:query sql="select GROUP_CONCAT(entry_id SEPARATOR '|') as market_ids from exp_channel_data where channel_id=3 AND field_id_12 LIKE CONCAT('%', DAYNAME(from_unixtime({exp:stash:delivery_day})), '%')" parse="inward"}
    {market_ids}
{/exp:query}
{/exp:stash:set}
```

This sets a value for the markets that I use later on in the page.

However, sometimes the stash value inside the SQL statement ({exp:stash:delivery_day}) wont be set. Typically if the user has clicked a link and not entered the site through our pre-determined route.

I've tried adding a conditional around whole statement, but it doesn't appear to be working because it's still executing the SQL statement:

```
{exp:stash:set name="market_ids" parse_tags="yes"}
{if "{exp:stash:not_empty name='delivery_day'}"}    
{exp:query sql="select GROUP_CONCAT(entry_id SEPARATOR '|') as market_ids from exp_channel_data where channel_id=3 AND field_id_12 LIKE CONCAT('%', DAYNAME(from_unixtime({exp:stash:delivery_day})), '%')" parse="inward"}
    {market_ids}
{/exp:query}
{/if}
{/exp:stash:set}
```

Anyone offer any advice on the best way to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding `parse_conditionals="yes"` to the `set` parameters? Alternatively, reversing the wrapping to put the conditional on the outside of the `set` tags?

Answer (score 1):

You could just do this to check the delivery_day value.

```
{if "{exp:stash:delivery_day}" != ""} 
  ... your code ...
{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use {switchee} on stash:delivery_day you can even have a {case} to display something when the delivery day was not set:

```
{exp:switchee variable="stash:delivery_day" parse="inward"}
  {case value=""}
    No delivery day set
  {/case}
  {case default="yes"}
    ...do query...
  {/case}
{/exp:switchee}
```